# How to run the application on previous versions

Tags: iphone

Iam developing one iPad application in Xcode 4.3 with ios 5 and iam using ARC mechanism.If i run this application from first version of ipad then application will be crash or not.Please let me know the problems with ARC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) is pretty clear on this:

> ARC is supported in Xcode 4.2 for Mac OS X v10.6 and v10.7 (64-bit
>   applications) and for iOS 4 and iOS 5. Weak references are not
>   supported in Mac OS X v10.6 and iOS 4.

Original iPads came with iOS 3.2, though they are eligible for a free update to 5.x.

Comment: My applciation is run on any ipad or i need to change any settings.

Comment: If you want to support iOS 3.2 you can't use ARC.

Comment: Then how to run my app in iOS 3.2 with ARC.

Comment: There is no supported way of using ARC on any version of iOS prior to 4.0. So the answer is: you can't.

Answer (score 0):

`ARC` is a compile time feature, so it will run.
But you should also check if you app runs on all support version of iOS that you will support.